# Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, java-8, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a Java application that uses the Google Auth library to authenticate with the Google Calendar API. I've downloaded the `credentials.json` file for my OAuth2 credentials from the Google Cloud Console, and I'm loading this file in my application like so:

```java
InputStream in = GoogleCalendarExample.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(in).createScoped(SCOPES);
```

However, when I try to run my application, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified.
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:170)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:143)
        at pl.szylak.googleservices.GoogleCalendarExample.main(GoogleCalendarExample.java:32)
```

I've checked my `credentials.json` file, and it does not include a `type` field. Instead, it includes an `installed` object with `client_id`, `client_secret`, and other details:

```json
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "PROJECT_ID",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "redirect_uris": ["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost"]
  }
}
```

I've read that the Google Auth library should be able to handle this type of credentials file without issues, so I'm not sure why I'm seeing this error. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and does anyone know how to solve it?

I've changed the values in credentials.json for placeholders.

---

This is my simple java code for adding some events to my calendar.

```java
package pl.szylak.googleservices;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class GoogleCalendarExample {
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/resources/credentials.json";
private static final java.util.List\<String\> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);

    private static com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service;
    
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        InputStream in = GoogleCalendarExample.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(in).createScoped(SCOPES);
        service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    
        // Call the Google Calendar API and add an event.
        addEvent();
    }
    
    private static void addEvent() throws IOException {
        Event event = new Event()
                .setSummary("Google I/O 2025")
                .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
                .setDescription("A chance to learn more about Google's developer products.");
    
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(new DateTime("2025-05-28T09:00:00-07:00"))
                .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
        event.setStart(start);
    
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(new DateTime("2025-05-28T17:00:00-07:00"))
                .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
        event.setEnd(end);
    
        String calendarId = "primary";
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
        System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in short you missed  "type": "service_account",

as the above code is trying to to read the credentials from a file  ( from - "/resources/credentials.json")but  it can not to find the required 'type' field in the credentials file
also crosscheck credentials  file is located  in "resources" directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have an incorrect service account JSON file - probably because it was generated and downloaded from the firebase console. The expected JSON file should contain the following in it:

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  ...
}
```

This JSON file can be generated through Google cloud console by clicking on the **ADD KEY** button highlighted in the attached screenshot.[image]